# How to calculate total sum of JList elements?

Tags: java, swing, sum

I'm creating a shopping cart simulation with a list of products as my inventory and a list used as the shopping cart which the user can scan items into. This, in theory, is to display the total cost as items in a JTextField below the list as they are being added to the basket.

To scan the items I have the following method :

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
  //Get the newly added list values.
  JList list = productList.getSelectedValuesList();
  double totalAddedValue = 0.0;
  double oldCartValue    = 0.0;

  //Iterate to get the price of the new items.
  for (int i = 0; i < list.getModel().getSize(); i++) {
    CartItem item = (CartItem) list.getModel().getElementAt(i);
    totalAddedValue += Double.ParseDouble(item.getPrice());
  }

  //Set total price value as an addition to cart total field.

  //cartTotalField must be accessible here.
  string cartFieldText = cartTotalField.getText();

  //Check that cartTextField already contains a value.
  if(cartTextField != null && !cartTextField.isEmpty())
  {
    oldCartValue = Double.parseDouble(cartFieldText);
  }

  cartTotalField.setText(String.valueOf(oldCartValue  + totalAddedValue));
  checkoutBasket.addElement(list);
}
```

Currently my main issue is that scanning one item into the cart will display the sum total of all items in the inventory list rather than just the one item I'm trying to scan. It will also print a line under the item name as such javax.swing.JList[,0,0,344x326,layout=java.awt.BorderLa... . How could I get around this issue ?

ItemList Class

```
public class StockList extends DefaultListModel {
    public StockList(){
        super();
}

public void addItem(String barcodeNo, String itemName, String price){
    super.addElement(new Item(barcodeNo, itemName, price));
}

public Item findItemByName(String name){
    Item temp;
    int indexLocation = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < super.size(); i++) {
        temp = (Item)super.elementAt(i);
        if (temp.getItemName().equals(name)){
            indexLocation = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (indexLocation == -1) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return (Item)super.elementAt(indexLocation);
    }
}

public Item findItemByBarcode(String id){
    Item temp;
    int indexLocation = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < super.size(); i++) {
        temp = (CheckoutItem)super.elementAt(i);
        if (temp.getBarcodeNo().equals(id)){
            indexLocation = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (indexLocation == -1) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return (Item)super.elementAt(indexLocation);
    }        
}

public void Item(String id){
    Item empToGo = this.findItemByBarcode(id);
    super.removeElement(empToGo);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
javax.swing.JList[,0,0,344x326,layout=java.awt.BorderLa... .
```

That is the toString() representation of a JList. The JList default renderer just invokes the toString() method of any object added to the ListModel.

```
checkoutBasket.addElement(list);
```

Don't add the JList to the checkout basket. You have to add each item in the list to the checkout basket separately.