# What is wrong with this method - (Adding Elements within a Jlist)?

Tags: java, swing, methods, jlist

I'm  currently in the process of creating a shopping cart simulation program. The main GUI contains two lists, one is a list of products or the inventory. (products stored within a .dat file which is automatically loaded upon launch) The other is blank and is to model my shopping basket. The idea is to be able to scan items from my inventory into the checkout basket. As this is happening i want a text field i created to dynamically update with the cost of all the items in the basket.

Below is the method for my scan button, which is supposed to perform the above :

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
      //Get the newly added list values.
      JList list = productList.getSelectedValuesList();
      double totalAddedValue = 0.0;
      double oldCartValue    = 0.0;

  //Iterate to get the price of the new items.
  for (int i = 0; i < list.getModel().getSize(); i++) {
    CartItem item = (CartItem) list.getModel().getElementAt(i);
    totalAddedValue += Double.ParseDouble(item.getPrice());
  }

  //Set total price value as an addition to cart total field.

  //cartTotalField must be accessible here.
  string cartFieldText = cartTotalField.getText();

  //Check that cartTextField already contains a value.
  if(cartTextField != null && !cartTextField.isEmpty())
  {
    oldCartValue = Double.parseDouble(cartFieldText);
  }

  cartTotalField.setText(String.valueOf(oldCartValue  + totalAddedValue));
  checkoutBasket.addElement(list);
}
```

Currently however scanning the item will add it to the list but print strange results in the total. (Adds 5.5 for each item regardless of their actual value**). It will also print a line under the item name as such `javax.swing.JList[,0,0,344x326,layout=java.awt.BorderLa... .`

Below are the classes for my CartItem and ItemList if they may help. Thank you.

-Cart Item

```
import java.io.*;

public class CartItem implements Serializable {

    private String barcodeNo;
    private String itemName;
    private String price;

    public CartItem() {

    }

    public CartItem (String barno, String in, String cost) {
            barcodeNo = barno;
            itemName = in;
            price = cost;
    }

    public String getBarcodeNo(){
        return barcodeNo;
    }

    public String getItemName(){
        return itemName;
    }

    public void setitemName(String itemName){
            this.itemName = itemName;
        }

    public String getPrice(){
        return price;
    }


    public String toString(){
        return barcodeNo + ": " + itemName + ", " + price;
    }

    public Object getID() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

-ItemList

```
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;

public class ItemList extends DefaultListModel {
    public ItemList(){
        super();
    }
public void addCartItem(String barcodeNo, String itemName, String price){
    super.addElement(new CartItem(barcodeNo, itemName, price));
}

public CartItem findItemByName(String name){
    CartItem temp;
    int indexLocation = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < super.size(); i++) {
        temp = (CartItem)super.elementAt(i);
        if (temp.getItemName().equals(name)){
            indexLocation = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (indexLocation == -1) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return (CartItem)super.elementAt(indexLocation);
    }
}

public CartItem findItemByBarcode(String id){
    CartItem temp;
    int indexLocation = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < super.size(); i++) {
        temp = (CartItem)super.elementAt(i);
        if (temp.getBarcodeNo().equals(id)){
            indexLocation = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (indexLocation == -1) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return (CartItem)super.elementAt(indexLocation);
    }        
}

public void removeItem(String id){
    CartItem empToGo = this.findItemByBarcode(id);
    super.removeElement(empToGo);
}
```

}

Comment: Quit asking and deleting questions: I gave you the same answer when you asked this exact same question 3 hours ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29242444/how-to-calculate-total-sum-of-jlist-elements/29242705#29242705. This is NOT the first time you have asked and deleted a question. It is extremely frustrating to spend time helping and give you an answer. Not only did I waste my time, but you have wasted the time of everybody else who has read this question.

Comment: @camickr: We don't need this kind of behavior on this site as it is not fair to the volunteers who try to help out. Thanks for the warning.

Comment: @camickr - My sincere apologies to you and Hovercraft Full of eels . My intention was never to waste your time, I was just looking for a more detailed answer as I am a beginner and was still stumped as to how to solve the issue. I have restored the question I deleted previously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're adding the **JList itself** to the check out basket, and that doesn't make sense:

```
checkoutBasket.addElement(list);
```

This, `javax.swing.JList[,0,0,344x326,layout=java.awt.BorderLa... .` shows that something is displaying the `toString()` representation of the JList, likely your checkout basket.

---

Regarding,

> Adds 5.5 for each item regardless of their actual value

I don't think your current code shows why this is happening, and you might want to create and post an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Other thoughts:

- Don't use String to represent price, but rather consider a numeric field, perhaps BigDecimal if you want to be accurate for money.
- You look to be mixing your view with your model too much. Try to keep them separate as possible, meaning, you should likely have some more non-GUI classes including one to represent the shopping basket, and any other nouns.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the swift response. How would I solve this ?

Comment: @user4702874: I don't know your problem well enough to fully answer this as your question seems to have gaps. Consider explaining more about what you're trying to do. But overall, you should work on making a better non-GUI model that can work with your GUI.

Comment: Hi I've made some changes to the initial post. Thank you.